# sed replace "func_name(old_args)" with "func_name()"

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am learning to use `sed`, I searched `sed` and tried a lot of ways, but there is always some scenario that I fail to cover.

Basically, I need to replace `func_name(old_args)` with `func_name()`. This `old_args` can be a lot of things, e.g., `foo()`, `foo(argument)`,`foo->ptr`,`foo_ptr->cotent`, etc.

So the question is I want to remove anything between the first `(` and the next`)`.

Any suggestions ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Should the statement `while(x>3)` be converted to `while()`? If not how can we tell function names from other language constructs that involve parens? Show a FEW lines of sample input as it's always trivial to find the text that matches what you want, but MUCH harder to not get false matches on text you don't want. Consider the edge cases that you think would be hard to identify correctly and include those in your input/output.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky to do with regular expressions because the language you're trying to parse is not, in fact, regular. sed cannot do this reliably, so we'll have to resort to Perl.

Fortunately, Perl regexes can describe more than regular languages; in particular, they support recursion. So you can write

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $/ = ""; } s/func_name(\(([^()]|(?1))*\))/func_name()/g' filename
```

and get the following behavior:

```
$ cat file
foo, func_name(foo), xyzzy, func_name(foo(),
                                      bar(baz(),
                                          qux()),
                                      quux()), bar();
baz()
$ perl -pe 'BEGIN { $/ = ""; } s/func_name(\(([^()]|(?1))*\))/func_name()/g' file
foo, func_name(), xyzzy, func_name(), bar();
baz()
```

The `BEGIN { $/ = ""; }` puts Perl into slurp mode (so multiline expressions are matched by the regex). Then the heart of this trick is the `(\(([^()]|(?1))*\))` capturing group, and particularly the `(?1)` in it that does the recursion.

Essentially it says: Match a string of an opening parenthesis (`\(`) followed by any number of things that match either anything but parentheses (`[^()]`) or *something that matches the regex for capturing group 1* (`(?1)`) followed by a closing parenthesis (`\)`). Since this is itself the regex for capturing group 1, it recurses into itself and matches a string of something with balanced parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, although it's still not perfect. OP appears to want to change C code, and C code can have string literals in it -- which can throw off the balancing (e.g., `func_name("abc)")`).  Hopefully this works for OP (the odds are not bad), but what you'd really want for this is a sort of libclang-based sed equivalent for C code. Alas, I don't think there is such a thing as yet, and writing one would break the scope of SO. :P

Comment: Yes you are right! I'm currently playing around with `flex` and `bison`. Probably (after hopefully getting more experience) I will start to answer such questions with a little parser example. Probably. ;)

Comment: To make this complete would take some doing. Imagine having to handle `#define CLOPAREN )` and `func_name(foo CLOPAREN`. Admittedly that's a corner case, but if you plan to be *thorough*, well... And this is not the worst shenanigans I can come up with. `#define CONCAT(x, y) x ## _ ## y` and `CONCAT(func, name)(x, "abc)" CLOPAREN`, eh? C is a beautiful language.

Comment: This can be done with `flex` and `bison` relatively easy and perfectly reliable. `C` is beautiful indeed but not too hard to parse..

Comment: Dunno. The preprocessor has its arcane corners, and it's stapled onto the rest of the language in such a way that you'd have to implement it in full to then apply the actual C grammar to its output. In any case, I'd probably start with libclang because they solved all these problems before (and solved them well). It'd probably be less work.

Comment: I'm just playing around with them for self-educational purposes. :) Will have a look at `libclang`. At least the source code will be interesting for self education... thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a greedy regex like this:

```
func_name\([^)]*\)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ3eI1/1)**

So, you can use:

```
sed -i 's/func_name\([^)]*\)/func_name()/' *.txt
```

If you want more sed information you can check this **[documentation](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)**

Comment: `.*?` is *non* greedy. `sed` does not support the `?` for non-greediness.

Comment: What if the input is `func_name(test(1));` ? You could (theoretically) simply use `func_name(.*)` since the `*` *is* greedy in sed. Theoretically because C code will contain many function calls and therefore `func_name(.*)` would also match `func_name(1); test(2)<--- closing parenthesis!`

Comment: @hek2mgl yes I know, but I based in the samples OP provided. My answer is focused on not nested functions. Regex has limitations for this, not all cases can be covered. But this is a useful comment for OP +1

Comment: This is not nested, but have more data on same line and fails: `echo "func_name(foo) data func_name(old_args)" | sed  's/func_name\([^)]*\)/func_name()/'`

Answer (score 0):

I think `(.*func_name\()(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^)]*(\).*)` do it all...

This would even handle cases where you have `func()+func_name(foo()+goo())+pi();`

Live demo: http://regexr.com/3akgc