# Can Sed match matching brackets?

Tags: sed

My code has a ton of occurrences of something like:

```py
idof(some_object)
```

I want to replace them with:

```py
some_object["id"]
```

It sounds simple:

```
sed -i 's/idof(\([^)]\+\))/\1["id"]/g' source.py
```

The problem is that `some_object` might be something like `idof(get_some_object())`, or `idof(my_class().get_some_object())`, in which case, instead of getting what I want (`get_some_object()["id"]` or `my_class().get_some_object()["id"]`), I get `get_some_object(["id"])` or `my_class(["id"].get_some_object())`.

Is there a way to have sed match closing bracket, so that it internally keeps track of any opening/closing brackets inside my `()`, and ignores those?

It needs to keep everything that's between those brackets: `idof(ANYTHING)` becomes `ANYTHING["id"]`.

Comment: And `my_class()` should disappear from output?

Comment: Why _sed_? Why not use something more powerfull, like a real programming language, like python, perl, C, C++, etc? It is theoretically possible in sed - it's a Turing complete language. Practically it's pointless, and handling `idof(")")` is incredibly hard. What can you tell about the vicinity of `idof`? Is it guaranteed to be one a single line alone? Is it guaranteed to be followed by a space? By a `;`? I.e. what about matching `s/idof(.*)$/....`?

Comment: @anubhava - no - anything within `idof()` needs to stay

Comment: ok then please include this part in question as well

Comment: Also can there be a line with more than 1 occurrence of `idof` strings e.g. `idof(my_class().get_some_object()) something idof(my_class().get_some_other_object())` ?

Comment: @anubhava - question updated. And yes, it's possible for a line to have multiple `idof` strings

Comment: @KamilCuk it took me 30 seconds to write that sed expression that works for 90% of my cases. If I need to write a program to handle this issue, I feel like it would take far longer. I was hoping there was a simple solution to this problem. As for your other questions: `idof` is rarely going to be alone on a line. It doesn't need to be followed by a space. No `;` either. `s/idof(.*)$/....` would work if the closing bracket was the last bracket on the line, which it's not guaranteed to be :(

Comment: Can you show example of a multiple `idof` strings on same line? How are those separated, just whitespace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sed replace "func\_name(old\_args)" with "func\_name()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110509/sed-replace-func-nameold-args-with-func-name)

Comment: May be you can try: `sed -E 's/idof\(([^[:blank:]]+)\)/\1["id"]/g' file`

Comment: `30 seconds to write that sed expression that works for 90% of my cases` Yes, which is what sed is used for. To handle more, use something else. From the above question Perl with lookarounds and regex recursion looks nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/idof\(([[:alpha:][:punct:]]*)\)/\1["id"]/g' input_file
```

Using `ERE`, exclude `idof` and the first opening parenthesis.

As a literal closing parenthesis is also excluded, everything in-between the capture parenthesis including additional parenthesis will be captured.

`[[:alpha:]]` will match all alphabetic characters including upper and lower case while `[[:punct:]]` will capture punctuation characters including `().-{}` and more.

The `g` option will make the substitution as many times as the pattern is found.

Comment: This seems to work amazingly well. I don't think SO likes answers that are almost entirely code though - this might get flagged. If you have some insight as to why this works so well, that would be great.

Comment: @John That is great! I find I learn better without an explanation so I can play with the answers to learn how and why they work by myself and grasp a better understanding of it, hence, I answer the way I'd prefer answers to be. However, if requested, I always add an explanation. Please check edit.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can write a regex that will handle all combinations of `idof(....)` up to some limit of nested `()` calls inside `....`. Such regex would have to list with all possible combinations of calls, like `idof(one(two(three)))` or `idof(one(two(three)four(five))` you can match with an appropriate regex like `idof([^()]*([^()]*([^()]*)[^()]*)[^()]*)` or `idof([^()]*([^()]*([^()]*)[^()]*([^()]*)[^()]*)` respectively.

The following regex handles only some cases, but shows the complexity and general path. Writing a regex to handle all possible cases to "eat" everything in front of the trailing `)` is left to OP as an exercise why it's better to use something else. Note that handling string literals `")"` becomes increasingly complex.

The following Bash code:

```
sed '
: begin

# No idof? Just print the line!
/^\(.*\)idof(\([^)]*)\)/!n
# Note: regex is greedy - we start from the back!
# Note: using newline as a stack separator.
s//\1\n\2/

# hold the front
{ h ; x ; s/\n.*// ; x ; s/[^\n]*\n// ; }

: handle_brackets

# Eat everything before final ) up to some number of nested ((())) calls.
# Insert more jokes here.
: eat_brackets
/^[^()]*\(([^()]*\(([^()]*\(([^()]*\(([^()]*\(([^()]*\(([^()]*)\)\?[^()]*)\)\?[^()]*)\)\?[^()]*)\)\?[^()]*)\)\?[^()]*)\)/{
    s//&\n/
    # Hold the front.
    { H ; x ; s/\n\([^\n]*\)\n.*/\1/ ; x ; s/[^\n]*\n// ; }
    b eat_brackets
}

/^\([^()]*\))/!{
  s/^/ERROR: eating brackets did not work: /
  q1
}
# Add the id after trailing ) and remove it.
s//\1["id"]/
# Join with hold space and clear the hold space for next round
{ H ; s/.*// ; x ; s/\n//g ; }
# Restart for another idof if in input.
b begin

' <<EOF
before idof(some_object) after
before idof(get_some_object()) after
before idof(my_class().get_some_object()) after
before idof(one(two(three)four)five) after
before idof(one(two(three)four)five) between idof(one(two(three)four)five) after
before idof( one(two(three)four)five one(two(three)four)five ) after
before idof(one(two(three(four)five)six(seven(eight)nine)ten) between idof(one(two(three(four)five)six(seven(eight)nine)ten) after
EOF
```

Will output:

```
before some_object["id"] after
before get_some_object()["id"] after
before my_class().get_some_object()["id"] after
before one(two(three)four)five["id"] after
before one(two(three)four)five["id"] between one(two(three)four)five["id"] after
before  one(two(three)four)five one(two(three)four)five ["id"] after
ERROR: eating brackets did not work: one(two(three(four)five)six(seven(eight)nine)ten) after
```

The last line is not handled correctly, because `(()())` case is not correctly handled. One would have to write a regex to match it.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation and the demo of the complexity. @HatLess's one-liner seems to handle everything I can throw at it great. I'm pretty happy with it so far, especially since any changes made to my code I'll be double-checking with git diff, so if it does break something, not only will I pick up on it, but so will my unit tests. Is there something that one-liner won't be able to handle?